# time series chart range on monday

Tags: java, jfreechart, timeserieschart

I'm using ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(...)
My horizontal TimeSeries is between the 01/03/2018 and 30/03/2018.

Is it possible to have an horizontale axis with just specific date ?
I'm using

```
serie.add(new Day(5, 3, 2018), 50);
serie.add(new Day(12, 3, 2018), 500);
serie.add(new Day(19, 3, 2018), 1000);
serie.add(new Day(26, 3, 2018), 3500);
serie.add(new Day(28, 3, 2018), 3600);
```

But on my chart, the horizontal axis show

7/3/2018
14/3/2018
21/3/2018
28/3/2018

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `SymbolAxis`, for [example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bjfreechart%5d%20SymbolAxis)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using SimpleDateFormat with desired format.

```
           SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = dateFormat.parse("put desired date value here");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
            }

            if (date != null ) {
                 serie.add(new Day(date), dValue);
            }
```